# Check current user's permission if the user has no enumerate permission in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

As we know, we can check user's permission by doing this:

```
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(path))
            {
                SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser;
                string loginName = user.LoginName;
                if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
                {
                    if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(user.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open))
                    {
                        //do something
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is my question, if current user doesn't have enumerate permission, how to get permissions on SharePoint object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [You mean like "system" permissions?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.systemaccount.aspx)

Comment: @bzlm I mean SharePoint permissions, like "Read", "View Only", "Full Control",etc.

Comment: If you want we can move this to our SharePoint site where you might get better answers. Flag or @ message me if you want to do this.

Comment: @ Kev♦ I am glad you can do this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by opening an "admin" web instance (creating a `SPSite` object and passing System account's user token to it). This way you do not have to worry about whether current user has or has not got enough permission.

```
SPUserToken adminToken = SPContext.Current.Web.AllUsers["SHAREPOINT\\System"].UserToken;
using (SPSite adminSite= new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.ID, adminToken) ) {
   using (SPWeb adminWeb = adminSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID)){
      if (adminWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.Open)) {
            //do something 
      }
   }
}
```

Of course, you better not do this on every page load as creation and disposing of SPSite/SPWeb objects is relatively expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have defined a function that takes a SharePoint list object, a Role type and a User.

- portal  : The sharepoint list or document library object.
- role : RoleType provided by sharepoint like Read, Design etc.
- user : user to whom you want to grant role on portal.

Hope it will help you.

```
public static void AssignPermissionToPortal(string portal, SPRoleType role, SPUser user)
        {
            try
            {
                // Run with elevated privileges  
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Site.ID))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.ID))
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                            SPList portalList = SPListHelper.GetSPList(portal, web);
                            portalList.BreakRoleInheritance(false);

                            //Add Readers on portal
                            SPRoleDefinition permission = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];

                            if (role == SPRoleType.Administrator)
                                permission = web.RoleDefinitions["Full control"];
                            else if (role == SPRoleType.Contributor)
                                permission = web.RoleDefinitions["Contribute"];
                            else if (role == SPRoleType.WebDesigner)
                                permission = web.RoleDefinitions["Design"];
                            else
                                permission = web.RoleDefinitions["Read"];

                            // Check the user Role on site level.
                            SPUser roleUser = uHelper.GetUserById(user.ID);

                            if (roleUser != null)
                            {
                                SPRoleAssignment assignment = new SPRoleAssignment(roleUser);
                                assignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(permission);

                                portalList.RoleAssignments.Add(assignment);
                                portalList.Update();
                            }

                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.WriteException(ex);
            }
}
```